# Are webresources once published always published?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Consider the following plugin...infrastructure build up omitted for brevity.

```
protected override void Execute()
{
    //Not all Targets are of entity so let's check first
    if (Context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && Context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
    {
        if (Message == EMessage.Create)
        {
           throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("InCreate");
        }
        else if (Message == EMessage.Update)
        {
            //I don't think this is right way to do this.
            if (PreEntityImage.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("componentstate").Value == new OptionSetValue(0).Value)
            {
               throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("UpdatePublishedMessage");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("UpdateMessageOnly");
            }
        }

     }
}
```

This plugin is registered for the Create & Update message on webresource.

So when the webresource is created my plugin fires and branches into the Create message section.

When the webresource is updated I branch into the Update section **AND** flow right into componentstate == published section!!??

I would have thought any change would have been flagged unpublished until I selected publish or publishall?

Some other details that may be relevant:

The webresource I am working with is a js file. Perhaps this is not the behavior for other webresource types like png?

The steps I am taking in updating the webresource are:

Open Test Solution
Open webresource js file
Open with text editor
Make Edits
Click OK---and plugin fires.

Thoughts, tips, edjumakation etc. greatly appreciated

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When saved and **not** published, Crm creates another record in webresources table. So for unpublished resources you have **two** entries: one record with componentstate = 0 and one with componentstate= 1.

I guess plugin works on the one that have 0 value. You might try query table to check if there's any with value 1 to determine if it's published or not. Or check any there paras passed to plugin.